# Which library is Protege using for inconsistent ontology explanations?

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api

I'd like to replicate the explanations feature in Protege within my Java program to provide explanations for inconsistent ontologies. I've been mainly using "owlapi" for other ontology-related operations, but it doesn't seem to have relevant methods to provide explanations. I've also found the "owlexplanation" library, but not sure if that is the one used in Protege. Could anyone please provide any pointers?

Comment: Perhaps this is [explanation-workbench](https://github.com/protegeproject/explanation-workbench).

Comment: That`s correct, developed by Matthew Horridge based on his PhD (nice stuff to read for interested people like me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[explanation-workbench](https://github.com/protegeproject/explanation-workbench), as mentioned in the comments, integrates [owlexplanation](https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation) in the Protege framework. You can use `owlexplanation` directly to get the same results Protege shows.